# How do I use ffprobe in Terminal?

Tags: ffmpeg, terminal, ffprobe

When I use ffmpeg I use it like this:

```
./ffmpeg -ss 00:30:00 -i inputvideo.mp4 -t 00:00:20 -c:v copy -c:a copy outputvideo.mp4
```

So how to I use ffprobe? I've tried this but I can't get it to work:

```
./ffmpeg ffprobe -v error -show_frames inputvideo.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ffprobe is a separate program from ffmpeg, not an ffmpeg parameter.

Comment: Got it. Found a download of ffprobe and got it working.